# Detect when a browser page window loses focus with Alt-Tab using pure JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

Is it possible to detect current page is in alt-tab?
This code works only if a new tab in browser is opened:

```
(function() {
  var hidden = "hidden";

  // Standards:
  if (hidden in document)
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "mozHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("mozvisibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "webkitHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", onchange);
  else if ((hidden = "msHidden") in document)
    document.addEventListener("msvisibilitychange", onchange);
  // IE 9 and lower:
  else if ("onfocusin" in document)
    document.onfocusin = document.onfocusout = onchange;
  // All others:
  else
    window.onpageshow = window.onpagehide
    = window.onfocus = window.onblur = onchange;

  function onchange (evt) {
    var v = "visible", h = "hidden",
        evtMap = {
          focus:v, focusin:v, pageshow:v, blur:h, focusout:h, pagehide:h
        };

    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.type in evtMap)
      document.body.className = evtMap[evt.type];
    else
      document.body.className = this[hidden] ? "hidden" : "visible";
  //console.log(this[hidden] ? "hidden" : "visible");
  }

  // set the initial state (but only if browser supports the Page Visibility API)
  if( document[hidden] !== undefined )
    onchange({type: document[hidden] ? "blur" : "focus"});
})();
```

But this code does detect neither new window of the browser nor alt-tab into any other programm. Is it possible to detect it? Or in jQuery?

**EDIT**
New page means Ctrl(cmd)+N (new window) hotkey. The code above can not detect this. Alt(cmd)+tab to another program - impossible to detect too.
The code above can only detect Ctrl(cmd)+T (new tab)

**EDIT**
I want to detect when a user return to my site from another application. That is, if a user closes any tab (e.g., by Ctrl+W) and returns to my site I can detect this action using the script above. But if a user returns to my site from another application (e.g., by Alt+Tab) the script doesn't work because `window.onfocus` will not be fired! That is,

```
 window.onpageshow =
 window.onpagehide = window.onfocus = window.onblur
```

doesn't work for Alt+Tab action. Is it more clear?

Comment: What does ***current page is an alt-tab*** mean?

Comment: @jfriend00 , updated

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want, but what about using `focusout` event on the `<body>` element. (You'd have to use jQuery to support Firefox.)

Comment: @StephenThomas, updated.

Comment: While this solution may work on it's own, it fails when checking through an iframe because under certain circumstances the parent gets the focus instead of the frame, therefore none of the focus events get detected.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can simply use the [`onfocus`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp) event on [`window`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp), like in:

```
window.onfocus = function() {
  console.log('Got focus');
}
```

If needed, you can also use [`onblur`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) for a more acute handling.

Comment: You was right. This is my fault. In the code above it was a wrong code. onfocus is fired on alt+tab.

Comment: i notice that for me (latest Chrome) `window.onfocus` does not fire, while `window.addEventListener` does work.

Comment: @Michael Strange: I just checked Chrome (after ensuring to get the latest version), and it works fine, both for `onfocus` and `onblur`.

Answer (score -2):

There is a Page Visibility API available:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false)
```

Comment: I don't think this API will help you when the focus goes to another window. Your page is `hidden` only if it's not the active browser tab, if the browser is minimized or if the OS screen is locked, AFAIK.

Comment: @kulak, If you look at my code you will see this event is not fired in alt+tab action

Comment: @jods on Ubuntu _OS Screen locking_ doesn't trigger the event.  Minimization and tab-switching does work indeed. (Tested Chrome 67, Ubuntu 16.04.4)