# ionic cordova - firebase stop listen "child_added"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a project with tabs, and I have a tab that listen to firebase Database "child_added". But if I go to another tabs it's continue to listen to database. Its possible to stop that when I go to another tab?

thanks!

Comment: You can use `window.onfocus` and `window.onblur` to detect when the tab gets/loses focus and then use `on()` and `off()` to attach/detach the listeners.. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383528/detect-when-a-browser-page-window-loses-focus-with-alt-tab-using-pure-js-or-jque

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen window.onfocus is not working for me.. can you give me an example please?