# JavaScript - How to force current window to be active?

Tags: javascript, http, logging, monitor

In JS - when you click outside the browser (say to a text editor), you lose "focus" of the browser window. One way notice this is that the cursor in, say, a text box, is no longer there nor is the textbox highlighted / glowing. How do you force this to always be "active"?

Comment: You can't do it from inside a browser.

Comment: That's default browser behaviour. It's not scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to take care to highlight or focus the element you thing should be focused and then detect when the page loses focus.

[Maybe this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383528/detect-when-a-browser-page-window-loses-focus-with-alt-tab-using-pure-js-or-jque/34401957)